# what is the real reason for not to automate AD_HOC executed test cases?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I read some articles on internet for automation testing. In there mentioned that AD_HOC basis executed test cases not suitable for apply automation. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "ad-hoc" executed test cases you mean "exploratory" test cases. While it is possible to add some randomness to an automated test, the challenge is to define the expected result.

When you perform manual exploratory testing, you have an idea of what the application should do and whenever you notice that the application doesn't do what it's supposed to do, or do something that it doesn't supposed to (e.g. shows a crash message), you can determine whether it's a bug or not.

Automated tests only perform and verify what you instruct them to, so if you perform random operations it's very difficult to define what should be the expected result in each case and what's not expected.

Moreover, even if you try to program the logic of what's expected and what's not according to the random values or operations that you perform, that logic would be pretty complicated, and the chances that you'll have bugs in this logic is not lower than the chances of having bugs in the application under test (AUT) itself, which makes your tests unreliable. Normally, automated test cases are very straight-forward, without `if` statements or loops, which makes them more reliable than the code of the AUT.

You can find more information in chapter 2 of the book I'm currently writing. The book will be titled "The complete guide to test automation" (by Apress), but as it's still not publicly available, you can read an older draft of it (titled "Succeeding with Test Automation") [here](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=B8A34EDB370C6811!1952&ithint=file%2cdocx&app=Word&authkey=!AKguF3SXbCvpoII).